# Hourly time series data in data frame: calculate total data per day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have hourly time series data in data frame I want to calculate total data per day in python.

I have tried resampling the data by mean on daily basis. But the problem is, it gives the mean data on daily basis but not the total count of the data on particular day

```
df2=df.reset_index().set_index('date').resample('1D').mean()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2=df.reset_index().set_index('date').resample('1D').sum()
```

Instead of using mean(), you can use sum() as the agg function.

Comment: i tried this, however it had incorrect values can you explain this briefly?? i used something like this df2=df.reset_index().set_index('date').resample('1D').agg({"index":'size'})  it would be great if you explain this aswell.ThankYou

Comment: Can you share a sample data for better understanding?